# Problem in defining a trigonometric equation

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

I want to define an equation and I already solved the probem for a special case. Here is the description:

Given:
$x_\phi$, $y_\phi, \alpha$

Unkown:
$r_k$, $r$

[image]

I solved this specific case where the center of radius with radius r is on the x-axis:

$$r = \frac{y_\phi}{cos(\alpha)} $$

$$r_k = x_\phi+rsin(\alpha)-r$$

Putting the equation of r in equation of r_k:

$$r_k = x_\phi+\frac{y_\phi}{cos(\alpha)}sin(\alpha)-\frac{y_\phi}{cos(\alpha)}$$

$$r_k = x_\phi+y_\phi(tan(\alpha)-\frac{1}{cos(\alpha)})$$

This worked fine for my first example. But now I have to solve a more common case where the center of radius r is not on the x-axis. Angle $\beta$ will be introduced and is known:

[image]

The problem now is that I cannot describe $r$ as a function of $x_\phi$ or $y_\phi$. At least I don't see it right now. I also solved this case with rotating the points $x_\phi$ and $y_\phi$ around the origin with the angle $\beta$. Then I have the same case again and it worked also. But I asked myself if there is a solution possible without rotation since $\beta$ is known...

Already started to describe the green line as:

$$x_\phi tan(\beta) - y_\phi$$

But since then I've been stuck and can't get any further.

Can anybody help how I can descripe here also $r_k$ as a function of $x_\phi$ or $y_\phi$?

Best regards,
mk3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative proof with the same result as the method of simultaneous equations (see other answer).

Consider the triangle $\triangle ABC$.
Side $AB$ opposite angle $\theta$ has length
$x_1 = x_\varphi - y_\varphi \cot\beta.$
Side $BC$ opposite angle $\beta$ has length $r.$
By the law of sines,
$$ \frac{x_1}{\sin\theta} = \frac{r}{\sin\beta}.$$
But $\theta = \frac\pi2 - \alpha - \beta$ and $\sin\theta = \cos(\alpha + \beta),$
so
$$ \frac{x_\varphi - y_\varphi \cot\beta}{\cos(\alpha + \beta)}
 = \frac{r}{\sin\beta},$$
whence
$$ r = \frac{x_\varphi \sin\beta - y_\varphi \cos\beta}{\cos(\alpha + \beta)}.$$

[image]

Now consider the triangle $\triangle OCD$. We have side $x_2$ opposite angle $\theta$ and side $r_k + r$ opposite angle $\psi = \frac\pi2 + \alpha.$
By the law of sines,
$$ \frac{x_2}{\sin\theta} = \frac{r_k + r}{\sin\psi}.$$
But $\sin\psi = \cos\alpha$ and $x_2 = x_\varphi - y_\varphi \tan\alpha,$ so
$$ \frac{x_\varphi - y_\varphi \tan\alpha}{\cos(\alpha + \beta)}
 = \frac{r_k + r}{\cos\alpha},$$
whence
$$ r_k + r
 = \frac{x_\varphi \cos\alpha - y_\varphi \sin\alpha}{\cos(\alpha + \beta)}. $$

Comment: Hi, thank you so much that worked. This answer is better to understand so I accepted this one. You made my day. Thank you!

Comment: I have an additional question to your solution. If the circle is an ellipse with semi axis a and major axis b this way seems not to work because I have an additional unknown (semi axis a in my case). Do you have a hint for the updated problem? I added another post. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321898/problem-in-defining-a-trigonometric-equation-ellipse

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the center of the circle with radius $r$ is $(x_P, y_P)$ in Cartesian coordinates. Each coordinate is a sum of two parts related to point $(x_\phi, y_\phi)$, and also part of the triangle with angle $\beta$ and hypotenuse $r+r_k$:

$$ \begin{align*}
x_P &= x_\phi + r \sin \alpha = (r+r_k) \cos \beta \\
y_P &= y_\phi + r \cos \alpha = (r+r_k) \sin \beta
\end{align*} $$

We can then rearrange this to a set of $2$ linear equations in $2$ unknowns $r$ and $r_k$, and solve.

$$ \begin{align*} r (\cos \beta - \sin \alpha) + r_k \cos \beta &= x_\phi \\
r (\sin \beta - \cos \alpha) + r_k \sin \beta &= y_\phi
\end{align*} $$

$$ \det \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\cos \beta -\sin \alpha & \cos \beta \\
\sin \beta -\cos \alpha & \sin \beta
\end{array} \right) =
\det \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-\sin \alpha & \cos \beta \\
-\cos \alpha & \sin \beta
\end{array} \right) = -\sin \alpha \sin \beta + \cos \alpha \cos \beta = \cos(\alpha+\beta) $$

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\cos \beta -\sin \alpha & \cos \beta \\
\sin \beta -\cos \alpha & \sin \beta
\end{array} \right)^{-1} =
\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)} \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\sin \beta & -\cos \beta \\
-\sin \beta + \cos \alpha & \cos \beta - \sin \alpha
\end{array} \right) $$

$$ \begin{align*} r &= \frac{x_\phi \sin \beta - y_\phi \cos \beta}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)} \\
r_k &= \frac{x_\phi(\cos \alpha - \sin \beta) + y_\phi(\cos \beta - \sin \alpha)}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)}
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Also +1

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, fixed.