# Problem in defining a trigonometric equation (ellipse)

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

I have an updated problem of my question from:

[Problem in defining a trigonometric equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319314/problem-in-defining-a-trigonometric-equation)

@David K gave me a very nice solution here. But now the problem is that since I do not have a circle but a ellipse the radius r is not perpendicular to the straight line with slope $\alpha$ anymore.
So I somehow don't know how to get to a solution because I think something is missing.

Given:

- $r_f$
- $\tau$
- major axis $b$
- slope $\alpha$ of straight line
- $x_\phi$,$y_\phi$

Target:

- Find value of minor axis $a$ with given values

[image]

I can solve this for a circle with radius r (see link from my last question) and I then thought maybe it is possible to transform the circle to a ellipse but since $a$ is unknown this seem not to work...

Here what I tried so far but I'm unable to continue because I cannot define $\beta$.

[image]

(1) $x_1=x_\phi-y_\phi cot(\tau)$

(2) $\delta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\tau$

(3) $\frac{x_1}{sin(\delta+\beta)}=\frac{r}{sin(\tau)}$

Putting (1) and (2) in (3) gives me:

--> $r=\frac{sin(\tau) (x_\phi-y_\phi cot(\tau))}{sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tau+\beta)}$

with unkown $\beta$

(4) $x_2=x_\phi+y_\phi tan(\beta)$

(5) $\Psi = \frac{\pi}{2}-\beta$

(6) $\frac{r_f+a}{sin(\Psi)}=\frac{x_2}{sin(\delta+\beta)}$

Putting (4), (5) and (2) in (6) gives me:

$a=(\frac{x(\phi)+y(\phi)tan(\beta)}{sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tau+\beta)}-\frac{r_f}{sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)})sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)$

but still $\beta$ and $x_\phi$ is unknown... Also I think $b$ can help me to find a solution for $a$, since b is known but I don't know how I can use $b$.

// edit 2021-12-07:
What about if $x_\phi$,$y_\phi$ is unkown?

// edit 2021-12-08:
After discussion with @Intelligenti pauca:

- Line with slope $\alpha$ and y-intersection $t$ is given (fix)
- minor axis $a$ and point of tangency $x_\phi$,$y_\phi$ need to be found.

Best regards
mk3

Comment: Your edited question has infinitely many solutions. You can take any value for $a$ and construct the corresponding ellipse ($b$ is given): on the ellipse there are two points whose slope is $\alpha$, thus giving two possible pairs $(_ ,_)$.

Comment: By the way: you'd better leave in place the original question and add the changes at the end, otherwise the already given answers will become hard to understand.

Comment: If this is the case I don't unverstand why the old one is overvonstrained. I think I could work further if someone would help me to get the angle $\beta$ but still nobody explained why I cannot receive a solution for this angle. You wrote at first I need one more equation but then suddenly everything is overconstrained. All the answers are a little bit confusing to me because the do not refer to my second picture. I will also edit my original post again later thanks for the hint.

Comment: I also tried it in a CAD program today. It definetly leads to one solution if I create an ellipse with fixed major axis $b$ and variable semi axis $a$, fixed slope $\alpha$ and fixed radius $r_f$ and angle $\tau$. So $x$ and $y$ is not fix and there is only one solution...

Comment: Your angle $\beta$ can certainly be found some way, given $\alpha$ or $b$. But I don't see the point of passing through $\beta$ when two solutions have already been given. What do you mean by "there is only one solution"?

Comment: Well what I want to do: I have a straight line (slope $\alpha$) an ellipse (major $b$ given, minor $a$ variable) and radius $r_f$. The ellipse is tangential to line with slope $\alpha$. and tangential to radius $r_f$. Also the minor axis $a$ is perpendicular to $r_f$. Also $\tau$ is known. If I create an ellipse with a fixed value of $b$ and $\alpha$, $r_f$ and $\tau$ is also known. Then $a$ will be calculated automatically and $x$ also. I thought that $x$ would be fix but if I increase $b$ also $x$ changes. That's why I think my original assumption is wrong.

Comment: See this construction, for the edited question: https://www.geogebra.org/m/thrmsrqv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132149/discussion-between-mk3-and-intelligenti-pauca).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the following vectors:
$$
\vec{r}_f=r_f(\cos\tau,\sin\tau),\quad
\vec{a}=-a(\cos\tau,\sin\tau),\quad
\vec{b}=b(\sin\tau,-\cos\tau),\quad
\vec{P}=(x_\varphi,y_\varphi).
$$
As $\vec P$ is a point on the ellipse we have:
$$
\vec{P}=\vec{r}_f-\vec{a}+\vec{a}\cos t+\vec{b}\sin t,
$$
which are two equations in the two unknowns $a$ and $t$. Solving them you can get $a$. Note that the value of $\alpha$ is not needed.

EDIT.

Here's a more geometric approach, exploiting our knowledge of angle $\alpha$:

- write the equation of the tangent line passing through point $F$, at the end of $\vec{r}_f$;
- write the equation of the tangent line passing through point $P$, at the end of $\vec{y}_\varphi$;
- find point $T$, intersection of the two tangents described above;
- find point $M$, midpoint of $FP$;
- line $TM$ passes through the center $C$ of the ellipse, which can then be found;
- once you have $C$ finding $a$ is straightforward.

Note that in this case the value of $b$ was not used in the solution.

[image]

EDIT 2.

Here's a solution for the edited question (see figure below). Now we are given an endpoint $F$ of semi-axis $FC$, the line $OF$ on which that semi-axis lies, a tangent line $PT$ and the length of the other semi-axis $b$. We want to find $a=FC$ and the position of tangency point $P$.

Let's draw the tangent $FT$ through $F$ (perpendicular to $OF$) and let $T$ be its intersection with the other tangent $PT$. Length $d=FT$ can be computed from the data, as well as the angle $\gamma$ between the tangents. Let's also set $p=PT$, a quantity to be found, and $\delta=\angle CTF$.

As midpoint $M$ of $FP$ lies on $CT$, then the fourth vertex $Q$ of parallelogram $FTPQ$ also lies on $CT$. The sine rule applied to triangle $FTQ$ gives $p:\sin\delta=d:\sin(\pi-\gamma-\delta)$, that is:
$$
\tan\delta={p\sin\gamma\over d-p\cos\gamma}.
$$
From triangle $TFC$ we then obtain:
$$
a=d\tan\delta={pd\sin\gamma\over d-p\cos\gamma}.
$$
On the other hand, $P$ is a point on the ellipse. If $H$ is the projection of $P$ on $FT$ we have then:
$$
\left({FC-PH\over FC}\right)^2+
\left({FT+TH\over BC}\right)^2=1,
$$
that is:
$$
\left({a-p\sin\gamma\over a}\right)^2+
\left({d+p\cos\gamma\over b}\right)^2=1.
$$
Inserting here the above result for $a$ we obtain a quadratic equation for $p$, which can be solved to yield:
$$
p\cos\gamma={d(b^2-d^2)\over b^2+d^2}.
$$
Finally, we can plug this into the expression for $a$, obtaining:
$$
a={b^2-d^2\over 2d}\tan\gamma.
$$

[image]

Comment: @mk3 Vectors have two components, right?

Comment: Sorry now I got it... I will try that and give you feedback if it worked.

Comment: Do you also have an idea if it is possible with pure geometry like I in my original post? Because If I take the same way like in the reference post proposed by @David K  I thought it would be possible to solve it just like a circle and then calculate $a$ by stretching the circle. The problem is that I cannot calculate the angle between $r$ and $b$ or $r $and $a$ in my picture since $a$ is unkown. But I think I just don't see it. The problem is that just $\alpha$ is not available to solve anymore since it is not a circle but a ellipse.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. But with this I don't receive a solution since TM passes not through the center C If I try it. I edited my original post with the current status of my solution. As you can see here $\beta$ is the problem  because r is not perpendicular to the line with slope $\alpha$ so I cannot find a solution like I did with the case of a circle. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @mk3 Line $TM$ DOES pass through the centre. It's possible that you misread my solution: I'll add a figure to help understanding.

Comment: I think this would help. Thank you very much. So you also think that I will not get a solution with my approach in the edited post?

Comment: Now I understand your post, thank you. The second point did confuse me a little bit because you wrote ", at the end of $x_\phi$. Now with your sketch its clear. I also got the solution for C by calculating the intersection point between TM and OF and also received $a$ out of it, just like you wrote. Just because I'm curious about my approach again. Do you see the mistake why it's not working?

Comment: @mk3 I corrected the definition of $P$. Your approach looks fine, the problem is you need another equation to find $\beta$, and that was to be expected, because you didn't make use of the ellipse at all in your reasoning.

Comment: Regarding the first method in the answer, if you decompose $\vec P$ into a component $\vec P_\parallel$ projected onto $\vec r_f$ and a component $\vec P_\perp$ orthogonal to $\vec r_f$, then $\lVert\vec P_\perp\rVert = b\sin t$ so you can solve for $t$, and then $\lVert\vec P_\parallel - \vec r_f\rVert = a(1 - \cos t),$ from which you get $a.$ I think the method is not as difficult as it might look at first.

Comment: So I think we now have a method that doesn't require knowing $\alpha$ and a method that doesn't require knowing $b.$ Either of these facts implies that the problem is overconstrained, so if you just set the "given" quantities to values that "look reasonable," the chances are that there will not be any solution that matches all the given values.

Comment: @David K Thanks for your answer (to both of you). That's the point. I want to describe it depending on $\alpha$ and depending on $y_\phi$ and $x_\phi$ because  $\alpha$ and $b$ is an input parameter (tangential constraint). I want to do it in the same way than with the circle in the reference answer. I know that one equation is missing in my edited post but I don't known from where to define it to get $\beta$. Everytime I try it I get new unkowns.

Comment: @mk3 In the case of the ellipse you are giving an additional information (the value of $b$) which was not present for the circle. As David K pointed out, the problem is overdetermined, i.e. you cannot give all the input values at will. In particular you must decide if you want to use $b$ or $\alpha$ to obtain the solution.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca. I still don't understand it completely. So I will not receive a solution with my approach even if an equation for receiving $\beta$ is missing? I just don't understand why it is working with the circle and just because I add a/b it will not work anymore. Because I add an unknown $a$ and a known $b$ so everything should be the same I thought... If you say this is not the case I will not further try it with my approach but I still have some hope because I think something is missing ($\beta=?$)

Comment: If $\alpha$ is unknown but all the other "given" information (including $b$) is known, you have just the right amount of information to get a solution and not too much.

Comment: And what if $\alpha$ is known and $x_\phi$ is a variable? $y_\phi$ is then connected with $\alpha$ to $x_\phi$. Would it then be possible to find a solution? Then I have to find $x_\phi$ and $a$. But then still the question is open how to receive a solution like in my edited post. Can you give me a hint if this would work? I edited my original post that $x_\phi$ and $y_\phi$ is not given but a varialbe I want to find.

Comment: I added a solution for the edited version of the question.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca that worked perfectly. Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. Just one last question. I think with this method it should also be possible to create another variant, where minor and major axis are given and $\tau$ need to be found. I already received a solution for $\tau$ by finding the root of your equation for a known value for $a$. But I think it should also be possible to derive an analytically equation for $\tau$. Is this correct? F, T, d and $\gamma$ are then an equation of  $\tau$.

Comment: If you know both semi-axes, then the ellipse is given and the problem becomes to find the tangents to the ellipse issued from a given point (which should be, I suppose, the intersection between line $PT$ and $y$-axis). This is a well-known problem and you'll find various methods searching a little. Here's a geometric method, for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433025/how-to-find-the-tangent-line-from-a-point-to-an-ellipse/2433224#2433224

Comment: Thank you very much for everything this should help me for the rest of my todo. I appreciate the effort very much.